# Transformation of a continuous rv into a mixed rv

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution

I'm stuck with this problem. I've done something, but I'm not sure if I'm correct or not.
Suppose $X$ is a r.v that has a uniform distribution over the interval $[-2,2]$. What is $F_Y(y)$ and $f_Y(y)$ if $Y =g(X)$ where $g$ is a piecewise linear function defined by $$g(x) =   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      -1&\text{if} &x < -1 \\
      x & \text{if}&-1\leq x\leq 1 \\
      1&\text{if}&x>1 \\
\end{array} 
\right. $$

Here's what I've done so far.
$$Y = g(X) =   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      -1&\text{if} &X < -1 \\
      X & \text{if}&-1\leq x\leq 1 \\
      1&\text{if}&X>1 \\
\end{array}\right.  $$

Therefore, we can say that the range of $Y$ is: $R_{Y} = [-1,1]$, which means that $F_{y}(y) = 0$ for all $y<-1$ and $F_{Y}(y) = 1$ for all $y>1$

Then, I computed $P(Y=-1)$ and $P(Y=1)$. I got the following: $$P(Y=-1)\\ = P(g(X) = -1) \\ =P(-2<X<-1) + P(X=-1) \\=P(-2<X<1) \\ = \frac{1}{4}$$

We get the same result for $P(Y = 1)$.

Now, let $y \in ]-1,1[$, then we have that $P(-1<Y<1) = P(-1<X<-1) = \frac{1}{2}$

So, assuming I didn't make any mistake so far, I would say that$$F_{Y}(y) =   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \frac{1}{4}&\text{if} &y= -1 \\
      \frac{1}{2} & \text{if}&-1\leq y\leq 1 \\
      \frac{1}{4}&\text{if}&y=1 \\
\end{array}
\right. $$

Now, I don't exactly know how to get the probability density function. The answer sheet says the following:

> $f_Y(y) = 0$ for $|y| > 1$, $f_Y(y) = 1/4$ for $|y| < 1$ and $f_Y(y) = \delta(|y|-1)/4$, where $\delta(x)$ is the dirac function (i.e. $\delta(x)=   \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
>       \infty&\text{if} &x= 0 \\
>       0 & \text{if}& x\neq 0
> \end{array}
> \right.$)

The answer sheet doesn't say anything about $F_Y(y)$ and I have no idea how I am supposed to find $f_Y(y)$ from $F_Y(y)$

Comment: So what is $F_Y(y)$ for $y\in (-1,+1)$ then? I'm not sure what you mean by $f_Y$ here. Not every random variable has a density wrt some measure

Comment: You're right, I wasn't clear enough. $F_Y(y)$ refers to the CDF of $Y$ and $f_Y(y)$ refers to the PDF of $Y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you wrote until your definition $F_Y$ is correct. Recall that:

$$F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}[Y\le y]$$

So if $-1<y<1$:

$$F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}[g(X)\le y]=\mathbb{P}[-2\le X\le y]=\frac{y+2}{4}$$

Providing that it makes sense for you to consider probability density functions with infinite values, you can get $f_Y$ from $F_Y$ by differentiating:

$$f_Y(y)=F_Y'(y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0& \text{if}& |y|>1\\
\infty& \text{if}& |y|=1\\
1/4& \text{if}& |y|<1\\
\end{array}
\right. $$

Comment: I got it, thanks